# How to fetch input image url to another input using of angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs, uploadcare

- Hi all i am using MEAN stack in my Web portal with AngularJS as my front-end,
- In my portal i want to upload user profile image, so i have used `uplodcare`platform to upload the images in my portal.
- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p4OTqC5NQi83SKCBjfpr?p=preview)
- after chooses the Image we get that image url in `upload input`, then we need to fetch that url into below input to store in backend. so we tried to get the solution like `ng-bind="userimg=img" value="{{img}}"` which is not working. please check and update us thanks.

**My Code :-**

```
<div>
    <label >Upload Img</label>
  <input ng-model="img" role="uploadcare-uploader" name="content" data-public-key="240426036fd9daf2d723" data-images-only />

</div>

<div>
    <label for="quantity">Fetch above input value in this input</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userimg" ng-bind="userimg=img" value="{{img}}">

</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code in the question body.  Links to sites external sites may change in the future, rendering this external information useless in the future.

Comment: that being said, the documentation for uploadcare-uploader describes the process you are asking about, in the section for `onUploadComplete`.  https://uploadcare.com/docs/api_reference/javascript/widget/#widget-on-upload-complete

Comment: @Claies if possible please update my plunker as well to know the exact solution thanks

Comment: 1. it's a good idea not to use your public api keys when asking questions on SO
2. you don't have to load both jQuery and full Uploadcare script. Use either jQuery that is bundled with Uploadcare lib or load Uploadcare lib without jQuery: https://uploadcare.com/docs/uploads/widget/install/#types-of-bundles
3. as @Claies have mentioned, don't use external sites to show the code and especially ask to fix that for you